# gradle: application run args can not pass system properties

Tags: gradle

Gradle 5.4.1

```
apply plugin: application

run {
   main = "mypackage.Foo"
}
```

Run:

```
gradlew run --args="-Dfoo=bar -Dhello=world"
```

Trying to pass the system properties using --args when running the application. But they were not set.

Answer (score 0):

`gradlew -Dfoo=bar -Dhello=world run --args="arg1"`

`--args` are what's passed to the main method.

Comment: yes,  that is the question. -D in the args were not passed to the JVM running the main class.

Answer (score 0):

You would need explicitly copy system properties from CLI into the corresponding run command/plugin system properties, unfortunatelly:

```
// The run task added by the application plugin is also of type JavaExec.
tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    // Assign all Java system properties from the command line to the JavaExec task.
    systemProperties System.properties
}
```